# Field norm well-behaved with respect to minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, minimal-polynomials

I'm not sure if this property is standard but this is what some examples suggested:

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be algebraic numbers. Is it true that
$$|N_{\mathbb Q(\alpha) / \mathbb Q}(min_{\beta / \mathbb Q}(\alpha))| = |N_{\mathbb Q(\beta) / \mathbb Q}(min_{\alpha / \mathbb Q}(\beta))| ?$$

I would be really obliged if someone could provide a proof or counterexample. If the above conjecture is false, can something be said in the case in the following special cases:

1. When the extension $\mathbb Q(\beta) / \mathbb Q$ is Galois?
2. When the extension $\mathbb Q(\beta) / \mathbb Q$ is a cyclotomic extension?

Comment: I think you just have two equivalent expressions for the absolute value of the *resultant* of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ and the minimal polynomial of $\beta$.

Comment: Any thoughts on my comment or on the answer posted by @Mindlack?

Comment: I understood @Mindlack's proof. I had a slight confusion about your comment on the resultant because the expression for each side of the equality mentioned above is $|\prod_{\sigma \in S} \prod_{\tau \in T} (\tau \alpha - \sigma \beta)|$ (with same notation as used by @Mindlack) and I wasn't sure whether all the other roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ would be contained in the set $\{\tau\alpha : \tau \in T\}$ (and similarly for $\beta$, since the extensions $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb Q(\beta)$ needn't be normal, but I suppose that's not a problem as $S$ and $T$ are embeddings.

Comment: That's right. $S$ and $T$ are the full sets of embeddings, so you do get all the roots of the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thanks, nice observation on the resultant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S,T$ be the (finite) sets of embeddings of $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $n=|S|$, and, for each $0 \leq k \leq n$, $(-1)^kb_k$ be the $k$-th elementary symmetric polynomial in the elements of $S$.

Then $min_{\beta/\mathbb{Q}}(\alpha)=\prod_{\sigma \in S}{(\alpha-\sigma(\beta))}=\sum_{k=0}^n{\alpha^kb_{n-k}}$.

So the norm $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ of the LHS is $\prod_{\tau \in T}{\sum_{k=0}^n{\tau(\alpha)^kb{n-k}}}=\prod_{\tau \in T}{\prod_{\sigma \in S}{(\tau(\alpha)-\sigma(\beta))}$.

So actually, the quotient $LHS/RHS$ for you is equal to $(-1)^{|S||T|}$ and the equality holds iff $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are conjugates or $|S|$ or $|T|$ is even. Otherwise, there is a sign.